# How can I pass a value from Batch to an Excel VBA macro?

Tags: c#, excel, batch-file, vba

I have a C# program which generates a CSV file, then opens an XLSM file in Excel (using `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process.Start`). The macro in the XLSM loads the CSV file and distributes data from it to specific cells. Eventually this will be C# generating a spreadsheet without macros that can be loaded in any office suite, and the CSV will disappear.

My problem is that this system now needs to support running the XLSM from anywhere on disk. It finds the CSV via a hardcoded relative path, which doesn't work from a user-specified location. I'd like to do something similar to passing a compiler parameter to define a constant.

**EDIT 1:**

Alternative approaches I have considered and rejected:

- Copy the XLSM to a standard location near the CSV and run it from there.

  I would need to copy the file back to its original location, but I don't know when Excel is closed to do that... Except maybe in Excel, but it doesn't know the original location, hence this question.
- Create the CSV file next to the user-specified XLSM location.

  The CSV file's location is specified in an NLOG configuration file, and changing the surrounding implementation to use a hardcoded path would be expensive. This is the only idea I've had that could work, but it would hurt.
- Create a Windows-based hard link to the custom location from the standard location.

  I can't assume I'm running on an NTFS filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porting your CSV generating program to a user machine you could:

- set an environment variable on the user machine to the target directory; e.g. (cmd line) `SET CSVPATH=C:\My\CSV`
- let the macro from your CSV processing XLSM read this environment variable using the `Environ()` function; e.g. (VBA) `MyPath = Environ("CSVPATH") & "\"`

alternatively, you could

- use a directory selection dialog in an "installation XLSM" to write the correct file path(s) to the target machine's registry using the `SaveSetting` statement
- let the macro from your CSV processing XLSM read the registry using the `GetSetting()` function to get the correct path

Comment: `Environ()` is reasonably close to my ideal solution. Ew, registry; I can't believe that made a close second. Many thanks. I was looking at compiler flags and didn't even think of environment variables.

Comment: One doesn't need to like it *g*, but SaveSetting / GetSetting() would hide things a bit better from the end user than an environment variable, if this is a demand. Still, if you know the key (e.g. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\[YourGroup]\Settings\[YourParam]`) it can be directly patched via regedit.exe and doesnt harm otherwise.